# iOS 8: Clicking Detail Accessory Button in UITableView results in different NSIndexPath by calling tableView.indexPathForCell in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

After Clicking an detail accessory button the call to tableView.indexPathForCell() returns the index of the next cell.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
  var objective:Objective

  if sender.isKindOfClass(UITableViewCell.self) {
     let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
     objective = objectives!.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Objective
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? ObjectiveDetailViewController {
           vc.objective = objective
           println(objective)
        }
     }
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case, `indexPathForCell` always return (0,0).

Comment: My issue is that indexPathForCell returns nil.